# Drinfeld's noncommutative projective line and noncommutative geometry

Tags: noncommutative-geometry

I apologize if my question is loosely formulated.
In the paper “[D-elliptic sheaves and the Langlands correspondence](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1993InMat.113..217L)” by Laumon, Rapoport and Stuhler, the authors define *“noncommutative projective line”*. Can their construction be viewed in terms of one of "mainstream" theories of noncommutative algebraic geometry?

Comment: Can you sketch their construction? Usually, asking questions which depend on putative answerers to read a paper are somewhat less attractive to those putative answerers :-)